# Total count before each month

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I would like to calculate the total count before each individual month. Imagine that i have a table like this:

table "order":
order_id(int), order_state(varchar2), changed_on(date)

order_state column has only 3 states - open, on_going and closed.

I would like to know before and for each month of the current fiscal year, how many where in on_going until each month.

example:

| order_id | order_state | changed_on |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | OPEN | 1-12-21 |
| 2 | OPEN | 1-12-21 |
| 1 | ON_GOING | 2-12-21 |
| 3 | ON_GOING | 4-12-21 |
| 23 | ON_GOING | 1-1-22 |
| 1 | CLOSED | 2-1-22 |

The results should be

| count(*) | date |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | OCT-21 |
| 0 | NOV-21 |
| 2 | DEC-21 |
| 2 | JAN-22 |
| 2 | FEB-22 |
| 2 | MAR-22 |
| 2 | APR-22 |
| 2 | MAI-22 |
| 0 | JUN-22 |
| 0 | JUL-22 |
| 0 | AUG-22 |
| 0 | SET-22 |

For 12-21 it should include order 1 and 3

For 1-22, order id 1 has been closed, include order 3 and 23

Assuming that current sysdate is May 22, until the end of the fiscal year it should return zero for future months.

This is where i'm at with the query

```
with fiscal_year_months as (

select to_char(add_months(to_date('01-10' || (to_number(to_char(sysdate, 'RRRR'))-1), 'DD-MM-RRRR', rownum -1), 'Month RRRR') mth from dual connect by rownum <=12 

) 

select count(*), changed_on
from orders
where order_state = 'ON_GOING'

right outer join fisca_year_months fym on fym.mth = orders.changed_on
order_by to_date(orders.changed_on, 'MM-RRRR')
```

but this query gives me the count for each individual month. And i want the count **until** the calculated month.

Comment: Can you also _specify_ the expected result. (Use same format as for the sample data.)

Comment: I edited the original post, as i can't draw a table on comments.

Comment: Hey, not as comment. Edit your question instead.

Comment: Gotcha, It's done.

Comment: Do you need only 2 months in the result or the whole year??

Comment: Current fiscal year. From oct-21 until set-22.

with fiscal_year_months as
(
select to_char(add_months(to_date('01-10' || (to_number(to_char(sysdate, 'RRRR'))-1), 'DD-MM-RRRR', rownum -1), 'Month RRRR') mth
from dual
connect by rownum <=12
)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `PARTITION`ed `OUTER JOIN` and the `LAST_VALUE` analytic function to find the most recent statuses for each order and then can aggregate:

```sql
WITH calendar(month) AS (
  SELECT ADD_MONTHS(DATE '2021-10-01', LEVEL -1)
  FROM   DUAL
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 12
)
SELECT month,
       SUM(status) AS cnt
FROM   (
  SELECT month,
         order_id,
         MAX(
           CASE
           WHEN month <= SYSDATE AND status IN ('ON_GOING') THEN 1
           ELSE 0
           END
         ) AS status
  FROM   (
    SELECT c.month,
           t.order_id,
           LAST_VALUE(t.order_state) IGNORE NULLS
             OVER (PARTITION BY t.order_id ORDER BY c.month, t.changed_on)
             AS status
    FROM   calendar c
           LEFT OUTER JOIN table_name t
           PARTITION BY (t.order_id)
           ON (c.month = TRUNC(t.changed_on, 'MM'))
  )
  GROUP BY
         month,
         order_id
)
GROUP BY month;
```

Which, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (order_id, order_state, changed_on) AS
SELECT  3, 'OPEN',     DATE '2021-12-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  2, 'OPEN',     DATE '2021-12-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  1, 'ON_GOING', DATE '2021-12-02' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  3, 'ON_GOING', DATE '2021-12-04' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 23, 'ON_GOING', DATE '2022-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  1, 'CLOSED',   DATE '2022-01-02' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | MONTH | CNT |
> | --- | --- |
> | 2021-10-01 00:00:00 | 0 |
> | 2021-11-01 00:00:00 | 0 |
> | 2021-12-01 00:00:00 | 2 |
> | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 | 2 |
> | 2022-02-01 00:00:00 | 2 |
> | 2022-03-01 00:00:00 | 2 |
> | 2022-04-01 00:00:00 | 2 |
> | 2022-05-01 00:00:00 | 2 |
> | 2022-06-01 00:00:00 | 0 |
> | 2022-07-01 00:00:00 | 0 |
> | 2022-08-01 00:00:00 | 0 |
> | 2022-09-01 00:00:00 | 0 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=731dcc276d307d22b8519c0ccd58d903)*

Comment: Hi. First of all thanks for your time. Please take a look at my expected results table and the reason behind those numbers. Thanks

Comment: @JoãoPires Updated

Comment: Thank you! Wish i could upvote your answer.

Comment: I still have a question... what if there were previous results before the calendar dates?